# python "ImportError: No module named xyz" on shared hosting

Tags: python, python-import

Similar questions have been asked on SO, I tried to follow their solution but so far no success. 
I have downloaded gspread from [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to use it in my project.

- Locally in mac + eclipse + pydev everything works fine.
- When I copy the code to my shared hosting environment (centos, bluehost) I get the error no module named gspread:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ReadSpreadsheet.py", line 8, in 
      import gspread
  ImportError: No module named gspread

Here is my directory structure:

```
src/
    gspread/
        __init__.py
    SpreadsheetReader/
        __init__.py
        ReadSpreadsheet.py (calls   import gspread)
```

Python version is 2.7 both locally and on shared hosting env. On shared I installed python 2.7 myself in ~/python.

I am not sure when it works locally in pydev why it doesn't work in the shared hosting environment.

Since I only develop locally and just use git pull on the sever to copy the code my preferred solution is not to have a custom code for the server. Setting env variables, etc is not perfect but acceptable.

Sorry in advance if the question looks similar. I was struggling for the past day with no luck. I think this should be a fairly common importing situation.

Comment: How does your Python path compare in your local environment and the shared hosting environment?

Comment: Why didn't you install Python normally on your shared host? Are you using virtual environments? Why didn't you install gspread normally using pip? There may be good answers to those questions but it seems like you've created a lot of problems for yourself by doing things manually rather than using the right tools for the job.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist For python installation I followed these steps: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/python-install, is there a better way?

Comment: @Feneric Both are empty. (Echo $PYTHONPATH)

Comment: How do you execute on the production server? You probably have to adjust PYTHONPATH. You could also install gspread via pip.

Comment: Set PYTHONPATH on your production server so that it find gspread, i.e. to include the `src` folder.

Comment: As I was guessing with my first question, it's likely a Python path issue. Your local environment & IDE are probably setting some path components for you, but it's up to you to do all that manually in the shared hosting environment. Ensure your Python path includes gspread.

Comment: I am trying to install pip on bluehost shared hosting, not successful yet.

Comment: After installing pip and using pip to install gspread the issue resolved. Thanks for the comments. @Two-BitAlchemist if you put your comment as an answer I can accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, installing pip and then installing gspread using pip solved the problem.

```
pip install gspread
```

The command above is mentioned in the [gspread documentation](https://github.com/burnash/gspread).